# Caffe module installation failed in Windows 10

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am very new to caffe. I was following this link:
http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/

When I ran this command: **python create_lmdb.py**,  I got the following error:

**File "create_lmdb.py", line 19, in  ,     import caffe ;
ImportError: No module named 'caffe'**

I tried to install caffe using this link : https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows, specially the following codes:

```
    C:\Projects> git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
    C:\Projects> cd caffe
    C:\Projects\caffe> git checkout windows
    :: Edit any of the options inside build_win.cmd to suit your needs
    C:\Projects\caffe> scripts\build_win.cmd
```

I have got the folllowing error:

```
    CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Project_git/caffe/scripts/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    ERROR: Configure failed
```

I downloaded Ninja, but not sure what to do with it. So I tried to change WITH_NINJA=1 to WITH_NINJA=0, then I have got the following error

```
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python34/python.exe (found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "2.7")
    CMake Error at cmake/WindowsDownloadPrebuiltDependencies.cmake:29 (message):
      Could not find url for MSVC version = 1900 and Python version = 3.4.
     Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:75 (include)
     -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also C:/Project_git/caffe/scripts/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    ERROR: Configure failed
```

Please let me know what should be my next step! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Step #1

Open build_win.cmd in notepad++ and update file line as below (to diable Ninja build)

```
:: Change to 1 to use Ninja generator (builds much faster)
if NOT DEFINED WITH_NINJA set WITH_NINJA=0
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

```
:: Change MSVC_VERSION to 12 to use VS 2013
if NOT DEFINED MSVC_VERSION set MSVC_VERSION=12
```

Step # 2

Open build folder which is inside the caffe folder and delete all previously generated files.

Step # 3

Python 3.6 is not supported officially and python 3.5 has some challenging issues. For a beginner i would recommend to install python 2.7 straight forward.

```
Install anaconda 2.7 [Anaconda  2.7][1]
```

Step # 4

```
Execute scripts/build_win.cmd
[1]: https://www.continuum.io/downloads
```

Reformat the code for easy to read

Comment: can you compile caffe with VS 2017 + Python 2.7

Comment: Still struggling. @JumabekAlikhanov Did you get any success ?